# Where to start in order to develop android apps/games?

Tags: android, java, c#

I've been wondering whether to start or not with android developing for sometime and I've finally decided to start now. My problem is I don't know from where.

On several pages I found people recommending java over C#, but when I check whether it is better to develop on Android Studio or Unity most recommend Unity which I find controversial as Unity is programmed with C#.

Any answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: The advantage Unity has is that it is "target neutral" - dev in one place, deploy to PCs, Macs, phones, etc.  If all I wanted was an Android app though, I'd do it in Java w/ Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on whether you want to develop games or standard apps.

**Android Studio** is the way to go if your app is structured in [activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities), which are basically screens. That is the case for most standard apps. For example when you open your browser on your phone, you might face a loading activity first, then a tab activity, you can possibly access a settings activity, and so on. If your app looks like that, then go for Android Studio.

**Unity** is a 3D-development platform. 3D is computationally intensive, especially when it involves real-time interactions, and development in this area requires you to use an already-existing engine, like Unity. *Do not code a 3D game engine by yourself*. If your app involves such requirements, you should use Unity, which provides you out-of-the box support for game, 3D, and real-time interactions in computationally-intensive renderings.

If your app is 2D, you can [still use Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/2d-game-creation), but there exist [a larger choice of 2D game engines](https://www.slant.co/topics/1476/~best-2d-game-engines-for-android) that you can use.

---

Useful links:

- Stack Overflow: [Unity3D or Android Studio for a android 2D game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008800/unity3d-or-android-studio-for-a-android-2d-game)
- Quora: [Is it easier to develop Android games in Unity3D or in Android Studio?](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-easier-to-develop-Android-games-in-Unity3D-or-in-Android-Studio)
- /r/gamedev: [Developing Android game- AndroidStudio or Unity?](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/400i7x/developing_android_game_androidstudio_or_unity/)